# Server fault (500) at require_once

Tags: php

I have a directory structure like this:

```
/var/www/html/
|
+-dir1
  |
  +-dir2
  | |
  | +-problem.php
  +-target.php
```

So the absolute paths would be */var/www/html/dir1/dir2/problem.php* and */var/www/html/dir1/targt.php*

I try to include the file `target.php` in the file `problem.php` with the line `require_once '../target.php'`

As far as I know this is the correct syntax to include a file, still I get a blank page with the HTML-code 500 Server error. I receive the same error if I use the absolute path.
If I browse target.php directly in the browser via domain.tld/dir1/target.php I get 200 OK so I suppose this file is intact. I removed all other data from problem.php for testing purposes, nothing changed.

Anybody else experienced an issue like this and has a solution?

Comment: how do you access `problem.php` from your domain? is it `domain.com/dir1/dir2/problem.php`?

Comment: Is the file readable by the server process?

Comment: @dchayka Yes, I access it like you wrote.

Comment: @EdHeal It is readable by the server process, it is set to rwx for owner, group and world (it's a offline test server so there is no security problem at the moment)

Comment: include paths are relative to the *current working directory*, not the file they're used in. And error 500 means you didn't look into the error.log.

Comment: @DBX12 what's the code inside `target.php`?

Comment: HTTP 500 is a general server error. Check the webserver's logfiles.

Comment: @mario I also tried absolute paths with the same outcome. But maybe we are on the right track now. I include a third file in target.php which is at the same level as target.php (/var/www/html/dir1/targets_include.php) with `require_once './targets_include.php` Maybe this is the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error. It was a typical beginners error. I required target.php in problem.php

Before @dchayka asked, I never thought about the content of target.php, as direct access via browser returned 200. But this was a mistake, as this file required targets_include.php which required problem.php

I used relative paths in these files. As @mario said, relative paths only work in the current working directory. Replacing all relative paths by absolutes worked.

Thank you, everybody :)